# Vim insert-mode abbreviations with normal mode commands

Tags: vim

I am looking to make a vim abbreviation s that if I type "prf" in insert mode it prints `printf("");` and immediately throws me back int insert mode but between the two quotes. I can't quite figure out how to do this...can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downside of insert-mode mappings is that each typed `p` will now appear with a delay in the buffer, as Vim has to check whether the full prf mapping should apply or not. Better use an *abbreviation*:

```
:ia prf printf();<Left><Left>
```

By omitting the `"` from the abbreviation, you can trigger that by typing `prf"`, and this avoids the problem described by @Dmitry Alexandrov.

#### Advanced variant

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Try `:inoremap prf printf("");<ESC>hhi`

It will type `printf("");`, escape to the normal (command) mode (`<ESC>`), move to the left 2 times (`hh`) then re-enter the insert mode (`i`).

Comment: Similar of course to write that in your `.vimrc` file, or whatever file you have for making the changes consistent.

Answer (score 1):

While mapping may be more suitable here indeed, I will answer your literal question: ‘How to use normal mode commands in abbreviations?’

Actually, you can do it in exactly the same way as you would use normal mode commands in the input mode:

```
:inoreabbr prf printf("");<Esc>2hi
```

or

```
:inoreabbr prf printf("");<C-o>3h
```

Disadvantage of using an abbreviation here is that it is expanded usually by pressing space, and this space is not dropped out – it is inserted. So by typing `prf<space>` you would get:

```
printf(" ❙");
```

where `❙` stands for cursor position. To get

```
printf("❙");
```

you have to press `C-]` instead of `<space>`.